# GPS coordinates Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, gps

Suppose i have `$longitude=2;` `$latitude =3;`
i want to get information from database

```
Select * 
from info 
where longitude is between $longitude + 2 AND $longitude-2  
AND latitude is between $latitude + 2 AND $latitude -2
```

how can i write this query to get information of specific area

Comment: I think it wold be better if you calculate your values outside of the SQL, for example, calculate a longitude_start and a longitude_end, ...

Comment: what you mean `specific area` ?

Comment: for example i only need those info that is near to my location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$longitude = 2;
$latitude = 3;

$longitude_min = $longitude - 2;
$longitude_max = $longitude + 2;
$latitude_min = $latitude - 2;
$latitude_max = $latitude +2;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `info`
WHERE `longitude`>$longitude_min
AND `longitude`<$longitude_max
AND `latitude`>$latitude_min
AND `latitude`<$latitude_max";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```